# how to show only child element with php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to show only headlines of a news paper site on my website with link to details page(newspaper site) .
I don't want to show header, footer or any other content of that newspaper. How can I do this with php ?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Please provide with more details and your codes.

Comment: By... not including the content that you don't want in the response?  It's impossible to answer without knowing more details.  In general, in your PHP code, if you don't want to show something to the user then don't include it.

Comment: If the site has a RSS feed, you could extract the headlines from there.

Comment: Suppose, I want to show headlines of http://www.bbc.com/news/ on my website http://www.example.com. If I use iframe tag then my page includes all contents of http://www.bbc.com/news/ . But I want to show only headlines.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a fine question. I understand what you're asking. I've wanted to something similar myself before. I don't know php, but I imagine that you want to extract the node you want from the DOM tree of the html.

Comment: Check whether the news website provide any kind of API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. read interested page to string ([file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) ) or [DOMdocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) / [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)
2. find interesting information in string (by RegEx or substring search) or in DOMdocument / SimpleXML (special function in DOMdocument / SimpleXML class),
3. echo it

**edit:**

If you like jQuery you can use [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

**edit:**

For [bbc.com/news](http://bbc.com/news) you can read RSS http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml - it is XML file with headlines.

**edit:**

It seems there is BBC News API -  http://api.bbcnews.appengine.co.uk/ - and you can get info in JSON